# SendKeys() in Selenium is too slow while typing words into a text box in IE browser

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am reading an excel row which has 4 or 5 cells and I am sending the data one by one to text boxes on a webpage using sendKeys() in selenium. But its too slow. Suppose I got a word 78845 from the first cell in the excel, then while inserting into the  text box it takes 5 seconds like 7 then 5 seconds then 8 again wait for 5 seconds and so on. Its too slow.

What can be done here?

Comment: Provide more info: 1. Which version of Selenium are you using? 2. Which type of webdriver (gecko/chrome/ie) & version are you using? 3. Which type of browser & version are you using?

Comment: You haven't said what browser you're seeing this with, but my psychic debugging powers tell me you're using IE 10 or 11 on a 64-bit Windows system, and you incorrectly assumed that meant you should be using the 64-bit `IEDriverServer.exe`. [Your assumption is wrong.](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html) Try the 32-bit driver. Of course, my psychic debugging powers have been letting me down lately, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I am using IE 11, IE webdriver and Selenium 3.3.0 and IEdriver for 64 bit windows

Answer (score 0):

Add "iexplore.exe" in Registry.

1.Press "Start button + R".
2.Type "regedit".
3.In opened Registry Editor window, navigate to below path:

```
HKEY LOCAL MACHINE > Software > wow6432Node > Microsoft > Internet Explorer > Main > Feature Control > FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

4.Right click on "FEATURE_BFCACHE" > click "New" > Click "DWORD (32bit) Value".
5.Enter "iexplore.exe" and save.

Now, run your Test Cases. It will be faster than previous.

Comment: No, for me test is not faster after doing this

Comment: Set security level same for all the zones under IE-->Internet Options-->Security tab. I set it as medium in all zones. And downgrade your IE version and try again. Thats all I got.

Answer (score 0):

- Try the `32-bit` version of `IEDriverServer`.

---

- If it doesn't help, you can set `Capabilities` like,

`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);`