# sendkeys entering data slow on chrome when running protractor tests

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, sendkeys

I am running my protractor automation scripts on chrome.I have to send large data in a loop to input box on website in my script . The data is in json file.
I am using "directConnect: true" in my config file.
config file is like this:
exports.config = {
        directConnect: true,
       specs: ['./RegressionV1_suite/elementCheck.js'],
    capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',

```
        chromeOptions: {            
            args: [ 'lang=en' ],
            prefs: {
                intl: { accept_languages: "en" },
            },
        },
    },

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000000
    },

    allScriptsTimeout: 10000,


};

Json file is like this:
{
 "Questions":
[
"issues in taleo",
"Taleo",
"taleo is not working",
"taleo password reset",
"getting error in taleo",
"Need access to  plant in sap",
"Modification of access in existing application access",
"Reinstate access of any application in-case of non usage of application from a long time",
"SAP T-code authorization",
"I m a new employee & need access to my computer & cemex applications",
"Need access to different plants in SAP/APEX/Command",
"Need access to application",
"Unable to access application",
"Authorization error",
"need access to command",
"need access to APEX",
"need access to sap prd",
"need access to cemex connect",
"need access to active suite",
"need access to loadmaster",
"need access to kronos",
"need access to business objects",
"need access to SAP BP1",
"need access to SAP CRM",
"need access to Lotus Notes",
"need access to SAP HR",
"I need access for",
"how do I get access",
"want access rights",
"want access",
"need access rights",
"need access",
"application access",
"I want admin rights",
"I want more access rights",
"I want some different rights on application",
"modify my access rights",
"my access rights got reinstated",
"reinstate access rights",
"security request form",
"calendar in outlook",
"create profile in outlook",
"not able to send emails in outlook",
"reset outlook password",
"schedule meeting in outlook",
"how do i reset outlook password",
"chax",
"How do I install chax",
"I have issues with chax",
"I need help with Chax",
"Install chax",
"how do I get webex",
"how do I signup for webex",
"I do not have webex account",
"new account in webex",
"request webex access",
"webex create account",
"Device not authorised",
"Unable to install AFARIA",
"need help signing BYOD Policy",
"BYOD Policy Sign",
"BYOD Policy",
"setup emails on phone",
"how to access emails on phone for the first time",
"I'm not able to install AFARIA",
"not able to access emails on phone",
"Bring your own device policy sign",
"calling card",
"How to order business cards",
"How to order cemex stationary",
"order business cards",
"Order stationary",
"stationary",
"need help with stationary",
"business cards",
"stationary and business cards",
"order stationaries",
"stationaries",
"Eplan is giving error",
"eplan is not working",
"I have issues with eplan",
"I'm getting error when trying to submit vehicle mileage",
"not able to report vehicle mileage",
"Password reset for eplan"
]
 }
```

and the spec file which calls this data from json file command are like this:
element(by.id('questionInput')).sendKeys(questions);

**This"questions" are nothing but the data from json specified above.for every loop one question is picked from json and sent as input in automation script.
initially the question is sent fast, after 30/40 questions the pace of entering the question in input box decreases.Question is entered one letter by letter increasing the execution time.**
referred these:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13919/selenium-webdriver-for-chrome-too-slow
[SendKeys() in selenium is too slow while typing words into a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890038/sendkeys-in-selenium-is-too-slow-while-typing-words-into-a-text-box)

**google chrome version - 61.0.3163.100(32bit)
 protractor version- 5.1.1
 npm version -3.10.10**

Can anyone please help me out in this!

Comment: You can add refresh in between the script or you can clear the cookies in between the script